# ArcGIS API for Flex : dynamic InfoSymbols

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, maps, arcgis

I am trying to add some InfoSymbols in my map, here is what I did :

```
<esri:InfoSymbol id="infoSymbol1">
        <esri:infoRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:DataRenderer>
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:VerticalLayout/>
                    </s:layout>
                    <s:Image id="eventImg" source="{imgSource}"/>
                    <s:Label id="eventName" text="{eventTitle}"/>
                </s:DataRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </esri:infoRenderer>
    </esri:InfoSymbol>
```

And I am filling a list from the data passed to the view, ( the application is a mobile view based app)

```
public function fillDataGrid():void {
            for each(var object:Object in data) {
                initDG.addItem(object);
                drawEvent(object);
            }
        }
```

Finally I add the InfoSymbols the drawEvent(objt) method :

```
private function drawEvent(object:Object):void{
            var myGraphicText:Graphic = new Graphic(new WebMercatorMapPoint(
                object.local.longitude, object.local.latitude));

            var event:InfoSymbol = new InfoSymbol();
            imgSource = "http://192.168.0.22:3000" + object.logo_thumb_url;
            eventTitle = object.name;
            event = infoSymbol1;

            myGraphicText.symbol = event;
            myGraphicsLayer.add(myGraphicText);             
        }
```

of course `imgSource` and `eventTitle` are Bindable, 
The issue is that I am getting

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   1120: Access of undefined property eventTitle.

And the same message for imgSource,

Any help would be much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare eventTitle before you assign a value to it.

```
var eventTitle:String = object.name;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but, I said "of course imgSource and eventTitle are Bindable" and in drawEvent i'm setting the values